# deny ssh,sftp, but allow svn+ssh

Tags: eclipse, authentication, svn, ssh, subclipse

I have a remote svn repository on a centos server and a user called developer.

I want the developer user to be able to use svn+ssh://[path to repository] from his local machine using Subclipse in Eclipse, but not be able to ssh to the server or sftp.

Currently the developer user can ssh, sftp, and svn+ssh. I want to make it so he can ONLY svn+ssh using Subclipse in Eclipse. He should not be able to access the terminal or any other files outside of those in the repository.

The developer user logs in using a user name and password.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up allowing ssh and sftp access and denying access to literally every single command